# name an object from a string

Tags: java, string, variables

I have been trying to see if something is possible in java for the last few hours
I want to use a string variable to name another object variable like so:

```
String s = newJpanel;
s = new JPanel();
```

Then for the newly created Jpanel to now be called newJpanel.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can't assign a `String` variable to a `JPanel` without producing a type mismatch error from the compiler. You can use:

```
Map<String, JPanel> map = new HashMap<>();
JPanel panel = ...
map.put("SomeText", panel);
```